# Configurate Spark by given Cluster

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to send some applications in python to a Apache Spark cluster. There is given a Clustermanager and some worker nodes with the addresses to send the Application to.

My question is, how to setup and to configure Spark on my local computer to send those requests with the data to be worked out to the cluster?

I am working on Ubuntu 16.xx and already installed java and scala. I have searched the inet but the most find is how to build the cluster or some old advices how to do it, which are out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you remote cluster is running and you are able to submit jobs on it from remote server itself. what you need is ssh tuneling. Keep in mind that it does not work with aws.

```
ssh -f user@personal-server.com -L 2000:personal-server.com:7077 -N
```

read more here: http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: Why tunneling? Wouldn't setting the master in the spark-submit command be enough?

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear. If the data are on your local machine, you should first copy your data to the cluster on HDFS filesystem. Spark can works in 3 modes with YARN (are u using YARN or MESOS ?): cluster, client and standalone. What you are looking for is client-mode or cluster mode. But if you want to start the application from your local machine, use client-mode. If you have an SSH access, you are free to use both.

The simplest way is to copy your code directly on the cluster if it is properly configured then start the application with the `./spark-submit` script, providing the class to use as an argument. It works with python script and java/scala classes (I only use python so I don't really know)